# How to make a full-width tab card in Bootstrap-Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm having something like this from the Docs in `bootstrap-vue`:

Card with tabs:

[image]

So how do I manage to design the tabs like this:

[image]

My current code:

```
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs card>
      <b-tab title="Tab 1" active>
        Tab Contents 1
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Tab 2">
        Tab Contents 2
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following simple CSS rules and add `full-width` class to `b-card`:

```
       <b-card no-body class="full-width" >
        ...   

      .full-width .card-header-tabs {
       margin-right: -21px;
       margin-left: -21px;
    }

   .full-width .nav-tabs .nav-item {
       margin-bottom: -1px;
       flex-grow: 1;
       text-align: center;
   }
```

and everything will be done

check this [codesandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/7kmwvmk6v0)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `title-item-class="w-50"` to make each tap title occupies 50% width

```
<b-card no-body>
  <b-tabs card>
    <b-tab title="Tab 1" active title-item-class="w-50">
      Tab Contents 1
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Tab 2" title-item-class="w-50">
      Tab Contents 2
    </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</b-card>
```

Comment: It turns out like this: [Result](https://imgur.com/a/BX7cRzg)

Is there any way that I could shrink the tabs on top of the card? Which means that the tabs take full size of the card header?