# Why does importing Buefy to my Vuejs project makes <h1> tag and some Bootstrap element display the wrong style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, buefy

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Buefy in my webpack-simple Vue.js project. When I import Buefy just like in the Docs, my  tag does not enlarge the text and the nav-bar in Bootstrap 4 displaying the wrong width.

My main.js file looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';
import Buefy from 'buefy';
Vue.use(Buefy);
```

What it should be when I remove the import Buefy:

[image]

But importing Buefy to my main.js lead to this problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Buefy` is based on the underlying [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) CSS framework which conflict with Bootstrap at some points as they implies global styles and class names that may be the same.

You can try to use LESS with Bootstrap to avoid conflicts but I feel this is overcomplicating and you should just stay with one or the other, known that there is a [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) port and that `Bulma` (`Buefy` also then) do exactly the same things as you can do with `Bootstrap`

Comment: I just use Buefy because I see some of the styles in Buefy but it is unavailable in Bootstrap-vue, but it seems to me that I need to stick with Bootstrap then :(

Comment: You can swap to Bulma/Buefy, it's a very fine CSS Framework; I'm doubting that Bootstrap miss anything (or his Vue port), but you might try your chance with other UI library like Vuetify or Element which are not based on Bootstrap or Bulma

Comment: The Bootstrap-vue doesn't seem to have a expand tabs like in Buefy, you can read my question on stackoverflow here, I hope you could suggest me a way [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217049/how-to-make-a-full-width-tab-card-in-bootstrap-vue)